# drupal 7 file field formatter on custom node for javascript (to set up jQuizMe)

Tags: drupal-7

I have set up a module with custom node type (I called jquizme, after the javascript jQuizMe that I really like using). I set up two fields for the javascript files I need to supply to make it work (after the general jQuizMe-2.2.js file you need to add another two javascript files - one for settings and one for the quiz content).

Drupal saves the files as myjavascriptfile.js.txt  - I tested them and they still work to make the jQuizMe interface - ok. the problem is, I want to add these files on the node page... the files will be different for each node. how can I access the files for the drupal_add_js() function so they will load the files for the node in question?

I tried setting up custom field formatters, but I don't know how to access the uri for the files of a given node automatically to put in the drupal_add_js() function (I can add a static file and it loads fine ... I did this with hook_node_view ( jquizme_node_view ).

So I just need a way to access the info for the files... how are they linked to each node? I can't find the connection. 
As you probably noticed, I am a module writing newbie, and I probably won't understand much related to object oriented programming sorry, haven;t progressed to that level yet), but I am open to any answer. I am sure I left out important info, but this it already getting too long.

I also set up a special page earlier on to just see if I could get jQuizMe to work in Drupal so that is still in the code.

I have tried many answers (last six hours or so... too much to say here), the latest of which is using tokens, but that is not working. Here is what I have so far:

> function jquizme_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
>      switch ($node->type) {
>          case 'jquizme':
>           $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_myfield', $node->language);
>           drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'jquizme') . '/jQuizMe.css', >array('scope' => 'header'));
>           drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'jquizme') . '/alert.js');
>           drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'jquizme') . '/jQuizMe-2.2.js', >array('scope' => 'header'));
>           //drupal_add_js($tokens['node']['jquizme_js1_field'], array('scope' => >'header'));
>           //drupal_add_js($tokens['node']['jquizme_js2'], array('scope' => 'header'));
>              break;
>      }
>   }

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whew!  I am 90 % there!  I did a search on how to find the fid for files attached to the node, came up with some work. this is my resulting code --- it is far from perfect but for my stage of learning, I am mostly happy.>>$nid = $node->nid;
         $node = node_load($nid);                                                                and from here I could access the filename. Then I concatenated it on the path which I know for drupal_add_js

Comment: the great thing is that I am getting the jQuizMe quiz to render, and the problem is now i get the drupal message Notice: Use of undefined constant und - assumed 'und' in jquizme_node_view() (line 40 of C:\xampp\htdocs\devel\sites\all\modules\custom\jquizme\jquizme.module).
Notice: Use of undefined constant filename - assumed 'filename' in jquizme_node_view() (line 40 of C:\xampp\htdocs\devel\sites\all\modules\custom\jquizme\jquizme.module).

Comment: how can I get rid of this warning message?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
// Let me assume that the field names of your two file fields
// are jquizme_js1_field and jquizme_js2_field for convenience..
function jquizme_node_view($node, $view_mode, $language) {
  $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'jquizme_js1_field');
  _jquizme_add_js_from_filefield($items);

  $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'jquizme_js2_field');
  _jquizme_add_js_from_filefield($items);

}

// Given the values of a filefield attached to some entity,
// adds them as JS files to the page.
function _jquizme_add_js_from_filefield($items = array()) {
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $fid = &$item['fid'];
    $file = file_load($fid);
    if (!$file) {
      continue; // Maybe the file got deleted..
    }
    $wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($file->uri);
    $path = $wrapper->realpath();
    // Ensure that the path exists and that it is a Javascript file..
    if (file_exists($path) && preg_match('\.js$', $path)) {
      drupal_add_js($path, array('type' => 'file'));
    }
  }
}
```